# renderItems dont have items

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function renderItems so it can be inserted into the return but it does not work
is displayed in the console undefined
if you insert this function into the return all works but I do not want to do so

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import PostService from "../../API/PostService";
import Loading from "../loading/Loading";
import "./ItemList.css";

export default function ItemList() {
    const [peopleList, setPeopleList] = useState();
    const [items, setItems] = useState();

    const postService = new PostService();

    useEffect(() => {
        postService.getAllPeople().then((peopleList) => {
            setPeopleList(peopleList);
        });
    }, []);

    const renderItems = (arr) => {
        arr.map(({ id, name }) => {
            return (
                <li className="list-group-item" key={id}>
                    {name}
                </li>
            );
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {!peopleList ? (
                <Loading />
            ) : (
                <ul className="item-list list-group">
                    {console.log(renderItems(peopleList))}
                </ul>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: `renderItems` does not return anything.  do `return arr.map(({ i ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to return from `renderItems`

```
const renderItems = (arr) => {
       return arr.map(({ id, name }) => {
            return (
                <li className="list-group-item" key={id}>
                    {name}
                </li>
            );
        });
    };
```